# How to use 'COPY FROM VERTICA' on same database to copy data from one table to another

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to copy data from one table to another in vertica using `COPY FROM VERTICA` command. I have a table having large data in it and i want to select few data (where field1  = 'some val' etc)  from it and copy to another table.

Source table has columns of type long varchar and i want to copy these value in another table having different column type like varchar, date and boolean etc. What i want is that only valid values should be copied in destination table, error data should be rejected.

I tried to move data using insert command like below, but problem is that if even there is a single row with invalid data then it 'll terminate process (i have nothing copied in destination table).

```
INSERT INTO cb.destTable(field1, field2, field3)
Select cast(field1 as varchar), cast(field2 as varchar), cast(field3 as int)
FROM sourceTable Where Id = 2;
```

How this can be done?

Comment: Normally in copy command error/rajected data can be saved in different file or table, only correct data 'll goes to actual table. Is it different in current case?

Answer (score 0):

`COPY FROM VERTICA` and `EXPORT TO VERTICA` are intended to copy data between clusters.  Even if you did loopback the connection, you would not be able to use rejects as they are not supported by `COPY FROM VERTICA`. The mappings are strict, so if it cannot coerce it will fail.

You'll have to:

1. `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE <conditions to filter out data that won't coerce>`
2. `INSERT ... SELECT <expressions that massage data that won't coerce>`
3. Export data to a file using `vsql` (you can turn off headers/footers, turn off padding, set the delimiter to something that doesn't exist in your data, etc) Then use a copy to load it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting it into a csv file:

=>/o output.csv

=>Select cast(field1 as varchar), cast(field2 as varchar), cast(field3 as int) FROM sourceTable Where Id = 2;

=>/o

Then use COPY command to load it back into the desired table.

COPY  FROM '(csv_directory)' DELIMITER '(comma or your configured delimiter)' NO ESCAPE NULL '(NULL indicator)' SKIP 1;

Answer (score 0):

Are they both in the same Vertica database?  If so an alternative is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cb.destTable;

CREATE TABLE cb.destTable AS 
SELECT field1::VARCHAR, field2::VARCHAR, field3::VARCHAR 
FROM sourceTable WHERE Id = 2;
```